# Generalization of Weil Conjectures

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, reference-request, etale-cohomology, weil-conjectures

is there a reference in English, besides Deligne's original publication: "La conjecture de Weil: II", not synthetic but complete that deals with the original argument of the generalization of Weil's Conjectures? Most of the references I have found use the Laumon method with Deligne's l-adic Fourier transform instead of the generalization of the Hadamard-de la Vallée-Poussin method.
Could someone be able to help me?
Thank you all

Comment: Perhaps the paper "Moreno, C.: The method of Hadamard and de la Vallée-Poussin (according to Pierre Deligne). 
Enseign. Math. (2) 29 (1983), no. 1-2, 89–128." is of some help.